# Stack Overflow Jobs site should use my Stack Overflow photo (right?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I just realized all my job applications (several) have gone out with my Google photo instead of my Stack Overflow one.  Is this expected?

I've posted a couple screenshots below.

This screenshot shows my conversations ***with a possible future employer***. It's using my "avatar" ***from Google*** which happens to be ***Trevor Phillips from GTA-5 holding an assault rifle*** - hardly something I want an employer to see:

[image: Trevor Phillips from GTA-5 holding an assault rifle - hardly something I want an employer to see.]

This screenshot shows what ***I see*** when I'm applying for a job. ***No indication*** that my murderous virtual alter ego is going to be sent to the employer:

[image: what I see when I'm applying for a job]

I've even changed my photo in Google, hoping it would get reflected back on Stack Overflow, but it hasn't.

This is kind of a big deal to me. I think it could have seriously negatively affected my chances with these employers I sent my information to.

UPDATE: Note, my Developer Job Settings shows this for my profile. It shows that my Stack Overflow photo is used - but it appear to be using my Google one on emails, instead:

[image: developer job settings]

Comment: There's a bug here, fix incoming. I've quickly patched your profile image URL on jobs until a prod build goes out

Comment: *Trevor Phillips from GTA-5 holding an assault rifle* - this bug is so wrong and so funny!

Comment: _hardly something I want an employer to see_ - unless this employer wants to hire a "killer"...

Comment: Sadly I don't remember any cheat command for this.

Comment: @DeanWard thank you! :)

Comment: @DeanWard Hmm should I see something different?  Still seeing Trevor in my Inbox and Sent Items (haven't actually tried a new msg though).  Is there anyway to have my past messages updated so they have my photo and not Trevor?  Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamPlocher gah, I didn't manage to push to prod yet and a nightly sync job overwrote my changes. Will fix as soon as near my laptop. Sorry about that

Comment: @AdamPlocher ok, temporarily updated again and I'll build out prod this evening with the actual bugfix.

Comment: @DeanWard you rock!  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just pushed a fix to production for this. Appears this has been a long-standing bug that affected those that were previously using an explicitly uploaded a profile image or an image from their Google account. If the profile image was subsequently changed to using Gravatar then it would not be correctly synced back to Jobs (which lives in its own codebase).

Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Ahh yes, this is my Wordpress (Gravatar) photo.  I setup my SO account so many years ago I completely forgot that I didn't upload that (I think).  Thanks again!